# How to show the post which checkbox is not selected

Tags: custom-post-types, php, plugin-development

I have custom post type and created one custom field checkbox called `is_featured`.
I have to show the post which is the checkbox is selected so I have used the below code and it's working

```
function isFeatured($atts){
global $post;
 $args =array(
      'post_type' => 'postname',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 30,
      'meta_key' => 'isfeatured',
      'meta_value' => 1,
      'order'      => 'DESC',
      'orderby' => 'post_date',
    );

$related = new WP_Query($args);
if( $related->have_posts() ) { 
$data = '<ul>';
 while( $related->have_posts() ) { 
        $related->the_post(); 
        $data.= '<li></li>';
                }
     $data .='</ul>';
    return $data;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

}
add_shortcode( 'is-featured', 'isFeatured');
```

Now, My issue is, How to show the post which checkbox is not selected?

Comment: You need to switch the position of `return $data;` and `wp_reset_postdata();`, i.e. call `wp_reset_postdata()` first. As for searching posts where the meta is not set (not yet added to the post) or that the value is empty, you can use a `meta_query` with a `'relation' => 'OR'` and two arrays, one with `'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'` and the other with `'value' => [ 0, '' ]`.

Comment: However, it'd be more performance-wise if you created the meta as a *custom taxonomy* because taxonomy queries are much faster than meta queries, particularly on large sites (many posts, users, plugins, options, visitors, etc.). You could even just use a special term in the default `category` taxonomy to mark/group posts that you want to be "featured". That way it'll also be easier to build your query args.. i.e. just use something like `'cat' => 123` or maybe `'category_name' => 'featured'` ..

Comment: @SallyCJ, Is this correct way to use ?   'meta_query' => array(array(
   'key' => 'isfeatured',
   'value' => '1'
  )
 ),

Comment: Yes, that's correct, for getting the posts with the meta value being `1`. For getting those where "the checkbox is not selected", it depends on what the meta value is set to when the checkbox is not checked. So you just need to adjust the `compare` and/or `value` accordingly based on your data structure (or meta value).

Comment: @SallyCJ, Thank you so much it's working for me

Comment: You're welcome. And you should post your solution (including the correct `wp_reset_postdata()`'s position) because it might also help others (and so that people know the question has an accepted solution).

Comment: @SallyCJ, Using your guide I solved my issue, Can you add the answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to show the post which checkbox is not selected?

I don't know what the meta value is set to when the checkbox is not checked (or maybe no meta set at all?), but you can use the `meta_query` argument for searching for posts where the meta is not set (not yet added to the post) or that the value is empty, e.g. in your case, "empty" could mean the meta value is a `0` (zero) or nothing (i.e. an empty string).

Hence in the following example, I used `'value' => [ 0, '' ]` which then automatically sets the `compare` to `IN` because we're passing an array of values.

```php
$args = array(
    // your other args here, but without the meta_key and meta_value

    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        // Search for posts where the meta does not exist.
        array(
            'key'     => 'isfeatured',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
        // Search for posts where the meta value is empty.
        array(
            'key'   => 'isfeatured',
            'value' => [ 0, '' ],
        ),
    ),
);
```

And here's an example if you want to use `meta_query` to retrieve posts where your checkbox *is checked* (and whereby the meta value is 1):

```php
$args = array(
    // your other args here, but without the meta_key and meta_value

    'meta_query' => array(
        // Search for posts where the meta value is exactly 1 (one).
        array(
            'key'   => 'isfeatured',
            'value' => 1,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Check [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) out for more details about meta query parameters in `WP_Query`.

#### Additional Notes

- There's a mistake in your code — You need to switch the position of `return $data;` and `wp_reset_postdata();`, i.e. call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) first.
- Shortcode should always return something, just as with filter hooks like `the_content`, so I'd add `return '';` at the end of your shortcode function. :)
- Meta queries like the one above are known to cause performance issues when the site gets bigger (many posts, users, plugins, options, visitors, etc.), so as I said in my comment, you should consider using a taxonomy/term instead to mark posts that you want to be "featured".

  After all, taxonomy was meant to be used for grouping things together, and taxonomy terms don't have to be titles such as `Featured` or `Foo Bar` and instead, they can be `0` or `1` to represent a boolean value.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.